# Dc.js no update between charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am starting to use an try to understand dc.js.

Unfortunately, I cannot manage to make my graphs update when I select one value in one graph, as all the tutorials/examples are supposed to work.

I have made a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/hqwzs3ko/12/

```
  var ndx = crossfilter(dataSet);
  dims = groups = {};
  dims.countries = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.countryCode;
  });
  dims.gender = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.Gender;
  });
  dims.emailFlag = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return d.emailFlag;
  });

  //dims.countries.filter("DEU");

  groups.all = ndx.groupAll();
  groups.countries = dims.countries.group();
  groups.gender = dims.gender.group();
  groups.emailFlag = dims.emailFlag.group();
```

The 3 graphs display 3 different dimensions, so filter applied to one show apply to the other?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Uhhh ... I'm stumped. In Safari it looks like nothing is wrong. In Chrome it is broken because Crossfilter is not loading properly. You can't really load resources from Github. Use something like rawgit.com. This may be causing a silent failure in other browsers?

Comment: @EthanJewett I have edited the jsfiddle in my post http://jsfiddle.net/hqwzs3ko/12/ to use cdnjs for external js - crossfilter and dc now both use cdnjs

Answer (score 0):

Okay spotted.

All is working perfectly here: http://jsfiddle.net/hqwzs3ko/22/

The idea is to define a reduce function based on the value that you want to be counted on, in my case the number of records (clients).
Therefore the reduce function must be based on a different value than the one used for the dimension creation:

```
groups.clientsPerCountries = dims.countries.group().reduceCount(function (d) { return +d.key});
groups.clientsPerGender = dims.gender.group().reduceCount(function (d) { return +d.key});
groups.clientsPerEmailFlag = dims.emailFlag.group().reduceCount(function (d) { return +d.key});
```

With this everything is fine!

Comment: Well, it is working, but that is not the reason it is working now :-) You'll notice that if I remove your reduceSums/reduceCounts, this version still works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/qm2cz34k  (BTW - reduceCount does not take an argument so that function passed to it doesn't do anything.) So why is it working now and wasn't before? No idea. Probably loading Crossfilter properly is what fixed it.

Comment: umm ... that's strange indeed. Crossfilter was loaded properly in my (local) version, so itshould have worked. The only hint I have now is that I used similar variable names for both dimensiosn and groups. Maybe crossfilter mixes these up (pure speculation)!
Anyway thanks for the feedback